# Can I use the NoCSS function for comment sections?

Tags: reddit

A lot of sites on reddit have a rather flashy design, especially gaming related subreddits.

Now while I wouldn't consider the subreddits i sometimes browse during work as NSFW, the design is often a bit too flashy for a workplace.

I know about the NoCSS function for a sub in general, but whenever I add +nocss to a comment section it's simply ignored. Can I somehow use the default reddit design in comment sections aswell?

For comparison the League of Legends subreddit [with](https://www.reddit.com/r/leagueoflegends+nocss/) and [without (**warning, flashy**)](https://www.reddit.com/r/leagueoflegends/) NoCSS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found out that `+nocss` isn't a function itself but a subreddit on it's own.

By using a `+` in the URL it is possible to browse the contents of multiple subreddits on the same page (explains the "multi" title). This causes the site to use the default reddit theme.

<strike>Since comment sections of posts are tied to a specific subreddit it's not possible to combine multiple subs.</strike>

Posts now support multireddit which means it is possible to add a `+nocss` (or any existing subreddit) into the link now to remove the default CSS of the subreddit.